# Dummit and Foote $p$-Primary Components of a Module over a Principal Ideal Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dummit and Foote problem 12.1.10 reads:

For $p$ a prime in the P.I.D. $R$ and $N$ an $R$-module prove that the $p$-primary component of $N$ is a submodule of $N$ and prove that $N$ is the direct sum of its $p$-primary components (there need not be finitely many of them).

I *think* there might be a typo here, or I might be misunderstanding the definition they give of $p$-primary components. I actually think this exercise is the same as 10.3.22 in D&F which is the chapter about modules in general. In that problem they define the $p$-primary component of an $R$-module $M$ (where $R$ is a P.I.D.) as the set of all elements of $M$ that are annihilated by some power of $p$. However, in this problem they are assuming that $M$ is a *torsion* $R$-module, and I think that's the crux of the proof. Otherwise we have $\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over itself. Every $p$-primary component of $\mathbb{Z}$ is just $\{0\}$, so certainly these don't generate $\mathbb{Z}$ via direct sum or anything.

My question is, does anyone have a definition of $p$-primary component which *does* make this statement true without assuming $M$ is a torsion module somehow? (I don't think it is true without the assumption but want to cover my bases.)

Comment: There is no such definition. Either assume $N$ is torsion, or prove that $N$ is a direct sum of Free part + Torsion part, and the torsion part is a direct sum of $p$-primary components.

Comment: Alrighty. Thanks for prompt response. Will see what my prof says when he realizes the error...

Comment: If you post the above comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such definition. Either assume N is torsion, or prove that N is a direct sum of Free part + Torsion part, and the torsion part is a direct sum of p-primary components.

Answer (score 0):

The definition that Dummit and Foote give of a $p$-primary component refers back to their Theorem 7, in which it is assumed that $M$ is a torsion module. So $M$ being a torsion module is part of the definition, but they don't make that obvious.